# How to verify that array contains object with rest assured?

Tags: java, arrays, rest-assured, hamcrest

For example, I have JSON in response:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"text"},{"id":2,"name":"text"}]}
```

I want to verify if a response contains a custom object. For example:

```
Person(id=1, name=text)
```

I found solution:

```
Person[] persons = response.as(Person[].class);
assertThat(person, IsArrayContaining.hasItemInArray(expectedPerson));
```

I want to have something like this:

```
response.then().assertThat().body(IsArrayContaining.hasItemInArray(object));
```

Is there any solution for this?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you check their documentation on anonymous arrays https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#anonymous-json-root-validation?

Answer (score 13):

This works for me:

```
body("path.to.array",
    hasItem(
          allOf(
              hasEntry("firstName", "test"),
              hasEntry("lastName", "test")
          )
    )
)
```

Comment: For me, I couldn't use the string directly and was forced to add `equalTo()` matcher in both strings ex: `hasEntry(equalTo("firstName"), equalTo("test"))`.

Comment: Ended up here again with another tip, when value is not of the same type this approach does not work, use something like this instead.
`hasItem(both(hasEntry("firstName", "test")).and(hasEntry("age", 18)))`

Answer (score 12):

The `body()` method accepts a path and a Hamcrest matcher (see the [javadocs](https://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.6/io/restassured/response/ValidatableResponseOptions.html#body-java.lang.String-org.hamcrest.Matcher-java.lang.Object...-)).

So, you could do this:

```
response.then().assertThat().body("$", customMatcher);
```

For example:

```
// 'expected' is the serialised form of your Person
// this is a crude way of creating that serialised form
// you'll probably use whatever JSON de/serialisaiotn library is in use in your project 
Map<String, Object> expected = new HashMap<String, Object>();
expected.put("id", 1);
expected.put("name", "text");

response.then().assertThat().body("$", Matchers.hasItem(expected));
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can also use json schema validation. By using this we don't need to set individual rules for JSON elements.

Have a look at [Rest assured schema validation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-schema-validation)

```
get("/products").then().assertThat().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("products-schema.json"));
```

Comment: I use JSON schema for validation, but in the current case, I want to verify that array contains an object, it means that object value is important for me.

Comment: As far as I know - 'matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath' works with JSON Objects but does not work with JSON Arrays. If you know a straightforward way to make an array work with this I would love to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Could validate in single line by extracting using jsonpath()

```
    assertTrue( response.then().extract().jsonPath()
        .getList("$", Person.class)
        .contains(person));
```